Proof attempt: $A\subset B \implies (C\setminus A) \subseteq (C\setminus B)$
Claim $$A\subset B \implies (C\setminus A) \subseteq (C\setminus B)$$
Proof
Let $x\in A$. Hence, $x\in A \implies x\in B$. By the contrapositive, $x\notin B\implies x\notin A$. Hence, $(x\in C \wedge x\notin B) \implies (x\in C \wedge x\notin A)$.
I have 2 queries:

Is my last step correct? I feel it is wrong. If I am wrong please correct me or provide me with a hint to proceed.
Does this work when $C=\emptyset$?

Edit: Actually the original question in Ethan D. Bloch's book on proofs is wrong, as the commentaries point. It should be $A\subset B \implies (C\setminus A) \subseteq (C\setminus B)$ instead of $A\subseteq B \implies (C\setminus A) \subseteq (C\setminus B)$.

The claim is wrong. Please double check what you actually want to prove. Maybe you want to reverse the inclusion.

@Martin Bradenburg How?? I found it from Ethan Bloch's book on proofs...

The claim seems wrong.  If $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ then $B$ might have elements that $A$ doesn't have.  If these elements are also in $C$ they will be excluded for $C\setminus B$ but will be included in $C\setminus A$.  So the statement is wrong.  But $A\subset B \implies (C\setminus B )\subseteq (C\setminus A)$.

Let $A={0}$ and let $B=C=\mathbb R$.

Typos happen.  But by Venn diagrams and intutive sense of containment it should be appear to be false.  Set minus is "taking things away"... taking more things away results intuitively in a smaller set.  (Of course "small" in an incorrect concept that can lead to great misunderstanding of we treat it literally... I'm talking basic intuition about inclusion.)

Or just try it with $A = {1,2,3}, B={1,2,3,4,5}$ and $C={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}$.  Then $C\setminus A = {4,5,6,7,8}$ and $C\setminus B ={6,7,8}$.  Note that ${4,5,6,7,8}\not\subseteq {6,7,8}$.

@fleablood with you modified claim, how would you prove that??

Note that in your proof:  $(x\in C \wedge x\notin B) \implies (x\in C \wedge x\notin A)$ it follows that $(C\setminus B) \subset (C\setminus A)$.  You actually proved what is correct.  Not what you you claimed (which would have been false).


Your last step is correct but it proves that $(C\setminus B)\subseteq (C\setminus A)$.  2) If $C=\emptyset$ then $C\setminus A = \emptyset; C\setminus B=\emptyset$ and $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$.  2a) If $C$ is empty then $x\in C \land ANYTHING$ is FALSE and therefore $(x\in C\land ANYTHING)\implies WHATEVER$ is vacuously true and every statement in your proof is still valid and the result is valid and true.


Actually.  Your arguement must include vacuous steps.  If for instance if $C\subset B$ then when you say "if $x \in C$ and $x \not \in B$..." well, that never happens.  But that's okay as the statement that follows will be vacuously true.   Any such hypothetical but nonexistant $x$ which would be in $C$ but not in $B$ would not be in $A$ either so it would, if such a nonexistant thing existed, but in $C$ but not $A$.   ... Still valid.

Your last step is correct, but it proves that $C \setminus B \subseteq C \setminus A$. This is true for any $C$, in particular for $C = \emptyset$. In that case both $C \setminus B$, $C \setminus A$ are empty and the inclusion is trivial.
If $A \subsetneqq B \subset C$, then $C \setminus A \subseteq C \setminus B$ is false. To see that, take $x \in B$ with $x \notin A$. Then $x \in C \setminus A$, but $x \notin C \setminus B$.
$C \setminus A \subseteq C \setminus B$ may be true in some special cases. For example, if $C \subset A$ (which is true in particular for $C= \emptyset$), then $C \setminus A = \emptyset$ and trivially  $C \setminus A \subseteq C \setminus B$.

If $C =\emptyset$ it does not follow that $A = B=\emptyset$ as we were never told that $A,B$ were subsets of $C$.  But it still follows as $C\setminus X = \emptyset$.

It also follows as the statements "if $x \in C$ and ... then....$" will all be vacuously true.

@fleablood You are right, I tacitly assumed that $A, B \subset C$. I made an update.
